# read function problem (not read all fields) in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i want to edit row. view file contains dropwons with Ajax. 
i used $this->data = $this->CourseBuilding->read(null, $id); but it cant read all fields of that id.

Can U help me.

Answer (score 2):

From http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelread - you can pass all the fields you want as a parameter to the read method like this:

```
$this->CourseBuilding->read(array('field1', 'field2', ...), $id);
```

or you can use this instead:

```
$this->CourseBuilding->findById($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->CourseBuilding->read('*',$id);
```

By using * as the first argument of the read method will return all the fields of that model.

Answer (score -1):

pass id to url name id

then when retrive data use `$id=$this->params['id'];`

and

```
$this->Your model name->id = $id;

$this->data = $this->Your model name->read();
```

U will receive your data

Thanks
Mehul